# How to tell a method is "dynamically defined method"?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am having a hard time understanding the concept of 'dynamic method'. I found this [blog post](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2013/03/03/dynamic_method_definitions.html) helpful, which claims

> "dynamic method" is methods with names or bodies that are calculated
>   at runtime, then defined.

But how could I tell a method is dynamically defined?

```
    class Foo
      def self.bar
        puts 'bar is statically defined'
      end

      define_method(:baz) do
        puts 'baz is dynamically defined'
      end
    end

    Foo.singleton_methods.include? :bar  #=> true
    Foo.instance_methods.include? :baz  #=> true 
    #??? shouldn't this be false according to the claim of 'dynamic methods'?
```

Comment: Get this book: [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Is there any answer to this question - *How could I tell a method is dynamically defined?*.

Comment: @Babai: after reading the book, you will know answer to this, yes.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks for the suggestion of the book. How about sharing some concrete thoughts regarding the questions?

Comment: Close vote is what you get for asking "Tell me everything about ...", which is neither polite nor is a sufficiently narrowed-down question. We don't take orders from you.

Comment: @sawa Sorry, I certainly did not mean that. I also edited the question, hopefully I am doing it right this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much difference between "dynamic" and "static" method, but `#source_location` might give you some hints. For the built-in methods, `#source_location` returns nil:

```
method( :puts ).source_location #=> nil
```

Now, to demonstrate the difference between "static" and "dynamic" methods, let us [install the pyper gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/pyper): `gem install pyper`. Pyper gem provides the extension of the Lispy idea of `car`/`cdr` methods. (`car` means "head", that is, the first element in a list. `cdr` means "tail", that is, all the elements except the first one.) Because `car` and `cdr` methods are defined "statically" by *pyper*, their `#source_location` is known:

```
require 'pyper'
x = ["See", "you", "later", "alligator"]

x.car
#=> "See"
x.cdr
#=> ["you", "later", "alligator"]
x.method( :car ).source_location
#=> ["/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pyper-2.0.0/lib/pyper.rb", 12]
x.method( :cdr ).source_location
#=> ["/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pyper-2.0.0/lib/pyper.rb", 13]
```

The return value of the `#source_location` method gives you directly the file and the line, from which the method source came. However, *pyper* also allows "dynamic" methods, which have not been defined in a static source file:

```
x.τaτ # equivalent of #car
#=> "See"
x.τdeadτ # a custom method that sellects all letters except the 1st from the 4th word
#=> "lligator"
x.method( :τaτ ).source_location
#=> ["(eval)", 1]
x.method( :τdeadτ ).source_location
#=> ["(eval)", 1]
```

The return value `["(eval)", 1]` indicates, that the method was defined by an `eval` statement, and you can consider it "dynamic" if you want.

Comment: I got your point, however running `Foo.method(:bar).source_location` and `Foo.new.method(:baz).source_location` give `["(pry)",2]` and `["(pry)",5]`, which does not allow any insight about dynamic or static. I think my example code may be too trivial. Or maybe the simplest way is to look at the source code, and that is just not rubyistic.

Comment: Nope, it's what the first line of my answer says: There is not much difference between "dynamic" and "static" methods. As for your `["(pry)",2]` output, it actually tells a story: That the method source code can possibly be found at the line 2 of the `pry` REPL. It's up to you whether you consider it dynamic or static, I'd consider it static. Actually, Ruby goes almost too far with remembering the methods' source code origin. In fact, when a programmer defines "dynamic" methods, it is the programmer's responsibility to keep the object space informed about what has happened.

Comment: (For example, I with my `pyper` shirk this responsibility. Reason: Laziness. No user has asked me to distinguish the dynamic methods or provide their source code; I have it only as a debug-time option.)

Comment: @BorisStitnicky The point you are discussing,some one edited the post and vanished it at all.. :)

Comment: @Babai: I see. The OP was originally more broadly formulated. I guess I make it a new answer.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Your answer more relevant to the actual question,which was put by op at 3rd position. I think you re-edit that question there,otherwise this answer will loose the value.. Even I like this answer. *+1*.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Aha, I was wrong from the very beginning! I was taking granted that every method defined by `define_method` is a dynamic method, which I now know is not true. And indeed the documentation of `define_method` says nothing about dynamic or static. Although `define_method` does not necessarily mean dynamic methods, it is a great companion(thanks for pointing out the blog post).

Answer (score 2):

As @Babai pointed out, the OP has been edited so as "not to be too broad". I do not dare to edit the OP back, so as not to cause close vote. Nevertheless, I undertake to answer the broadly formulated first version of the OP, or, rather, the question no. 1, when should a programmer use dynamic methods:

**Dynamic method definition should be used, when there are too many possible methods with different method names, that cannot be defined manually.**

Ultimately, this is a question of the language. When programming, every programmer is creating a language, a domain specific language (DSL) of some domain. This language can be good or bad. Good DSLs usually resemble the typical manners of the target field. Sometimes, you do not need to have too many method names, and you can handle the variability with parameters. Actually, the standard way is to use a limited number of Ruby method names, and provide the rest of the information as parameters and blocks.

However, sometimes, the characteristic language of the target domain does call for a large, or even infinite number of method names. For example, Lispy methods `car` and `cdr` allow for infinite number of combinations: `caar`, `cadr`, `cdadar` `cad....dadaaddar`,... Obviously, these methods cannot be all defined in advance manually. One could imagine defining just one method `cxr`, where `cxr( 'a' )` would stand for `car`, `cxr( 'd' )` for `cdr`, `cxr( 'dada' )` for `cdadar` and so on. But, arguably, `car`/`cdr` method family would lose its beauty by this. So, instead, I have in *pyper* defined a `#method_missing` on the `Enumerable`-like classes, enabling any combination of letters (`τaaτ`, `τadτ`, `τdadaτ`, ...) without having to define the methods statically in advance.

Another example that I can provide is my `sy` physical units library (`gem install sy`). Arguably, speed of 100 miles per hour can be comfortably written as:

```
require 'sy/imperial'
100.mile.h(-1)
```

But, I asked myself, is it beautiful? To make the DSL more similar to the way people express themselves in the domain of metrology, I decided to add Unicode exponents:

```
100.mile.h⁻¹
```

In exchange for the good looks, there is a problem: There are possibly infinitely many exponents: `-∞, ..., -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., +∞`. Again, it was necessary to define these methods dynamically by `#method_missing`. This way, arbitrary, even ridiculous exponents ar possible:

```
nonsense_magnitude = 1.m²⁷.s⁻⁵³
```

Comment: Great Effort indeed! :)

Comment: Whereas let me point the original asker to the article that had helped me to shed my fear of `#method_missing`: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/method_missing-a-rubyists-beautiful-mistress/

Comment: @BorisStitnicky That's a great article. Thanks for answering the 'when to use?' question, this is the one I appreciate more but can't ask because of the 'broad' rule. Great explanation!

Answer (score -1):

1. `def bar` is just a syntactic sugar of `define_method(:baz) do`
2. Actually there are no difference between a 'dynamic method' and a 'normal method' **once it's defined**.
3. `define_method` is usually used together with `method_missing`, this code below is a good example of 'dynamic method'

   ```
   class Foo
     def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
       eigenclass = class << self; self; end
       eigenclass.class_eval do
         define_method(meth) do
           puts "method '#{meth}' is dynamically defined"
         end
       end
       send(meth, *args, &block)
     end
   end

   foo = Foo.new
   puts foo.methods.include? :bar  # => false
   foo.bar                         # => method 'bar' is dynamically defined
   puts foo.methods.include? :bar  # => true
   ```

Comment: with `method_missing` it looks clear that `bar` is dynamically defined when it is called, which goes with the claim of blog post. Does this mean, in my code, `baz` is already defined before run time even though it's defined using `define_method`?

Comment: If you look at my answer, you will se that even after a method is defined, Ruby does keep some references about the source it came from.

Comment: @JunZhou: And btw., saying that `def bar` is just a syntactic sugar for `define_method :bar do ... end` is not entirely correct. The block-accepting `#define_method` cannot be entirely replaced by `def` statement, and vice-versa. Both of them are needed, and they do not do the same thing.